# Artifactory rtBuildInfo does not collect env variables in Jenkins docker pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I want to collect env variables inside of Jenkins declarative dockerized pipeline using Artifactory plugin.

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'node:10.16'
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage ('Build') {
      // This publish build info but without env variables:
      rtBuildInfo captureEnv: true
      rtPublishBuildInfo serverId: "Artifactory1"
      // This publish build info WITH env variables:
      script {
        server = Artifactory.server "Artifactory1"

        buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
        buildInfo.env.capture = true
        buildInfo.env.collect()
        server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So using scripted syntax it works, using declarative not. I was following this JFrog documentation: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Declarative+Pipeline+Syntax#DeclarativePipelineSyntax-PublishingBuild-InfotoArtifactory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `rtBuildInfo captureEnv: true` and `buildInfo.env.capture = true`

> set the Build-Info object to automatically capture environment variables while downloading and uploading files

which means env variables will only be collected during upload and download.

`buildInfo.env.collect()`, however

> collect environment variables at any point in the script

which is why the env variables are collected in your case. Declarative does not support a similar option.

Comment: Thanks. Extra information: I am pushing docker images as result of a pipeline execution. That action also does not trigger capturing env variables.